# Check if a file exists before loading it

Tags: dart, flutter, assets

What I want to do is load an image in a Material Widget to use it in a ListTile, but this asset might not exist.

```
class MyImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final imagePath;

  MyIcon(String iconName) {
    try { // check if imagePath exists. Here is the problem
      imagePath = check('assets/$iconName.png/');
    } catch (e, s) { // if not
      imagePath = 'assets/$iconName.png/';
    }
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(...here I will load the imagePath...);
 }
}
```

So, since I'm using a Stateless widget, I have to know beforehand if the image exists, otherwise I'll load a null right?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

In order to see whether or not a *file* exists in internal local storage of the app use:

```
import 'dart:io' as io;
var syncPath = await path;

// for a file
await io.File(syncPath).exists();
io.File(syncPath).existsSync();

// for a directory
await io.Directory(syncPath).exists();
io.Directory(syncPath).existsSync();
```

Comment: How to check if given path is filepath in device or network path from server?

Comment: @JayMungara You can use **isURL('path')** method from [Validators](https://pub.dev/packages/validators) plugin to differentiate b/w Local and Network links.

Comment: File(path).exists() returns a future bool. To implement this in a stateless widget, or to just check using if statement, use File(path).existsSync() which returns a bool data type.

Comment: @JayMungara - did you find an answer?

Comment: @CodeGeek your solution is not applicable to this problem.

Comment: @Nae Pls don't recommend the slow async API. Dart itself discourages this, see the Linter Rule "avoid_slow_async_io" -> https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_slow_async_io.html

Answer (score 43):

For me simply worked this:

```
import 'dart:io';
File("path/to/file").exists()
```

or, for checking it synchronously

```
import 'dart:io';
File("path/to/file").existsSync()
```

Comment: `await File("path/to/file").exists()` is the same as `File("path/to/file").existsSync()` right? Why do they both exist?

Comment: @Joran I think they exists because you may be in a closure which isn't marked with async keyword but you want to wait for the result. I think it's on purpose.

Answer (score 17):

Looks like you want to try to load an `ImageProvider` from a folder where the image may or may not exist and then, if it does not, load a fallback asset image (which you can be sure will exist as you'll put it in your root bundle).

Try this:

```
ImageProvider getImageProvider(File f) {
  return f.existsSync()
      ? FileImage(f)
      : const AssetImage('images/fallback.png');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for, but for some reason `f.existsSync()` always returns `false`.

Comment: Ok, I think that this does not work. `f.existsSync` is always going to be false because assets are not files. They are bundles within the executable, according to a comment from this new question I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653032/flutter-file-existssync-always-returns-false

Comment: As I said before, you don't need to test whether assets exist - you know that at build time. But in the comment you say "which I'll previously download (semi-automatically)", so these you will have written to a read/write folder and can test whether they exist.

Comment: I don't understand. These files are written to the assets folder, the assets folder is mentioned in the pubspec, then the app is compiled. Then I need to test whenever the user want to see some info from this team, if its icon exists because it's not sure that every team has its icon.

Comment: So, what you really want to know is whether an asset exists. The best way to do this is to include an additional (text? json?) asset that is a list of all the other assets. In fact, flutter creates one for you. It's called `AssetManifest.json`. It's an implementation detail, so may change, but seems to work for now.

Comment: Great! I'll take a look at that

Answer (score -3):

In order to see whether or not a file exists in local storage (as with image.network) now you can use :

```
Image.file(File("path/to/file"),
errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception, StackTrace? stackTrace) {return Text('file access error');
```

Comment: This does not answer the op's question.