# Load deafult image if Image.asset not found the image

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image, uiimageasset

I am trying to load an image with this code

```
CircleAvatar(
    child: Image(
    image: getImage(snapshot.value['img']),
    ),
),
```

but if the image is not founded I want to replace it with a default image and I try this code

```
AssetImage getImage(String image) {
    AssetImage img;
    try {
        img = AssetImage('images/${widget.categoria}/$image.png');
    } catch (e) {
        img = AssetImage('images/non_disp_big.png');
    }
    return img;
}
```

I allready add all images dependencies in pubspec.yaml
I just wanna replace the image with a default if not found it in the folder

This is the error:

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: images/produzioni-tipiche/biplano.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:484:44)
#2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:469:14)
#3      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:327:17)
...
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "images/produzioni-tipiche/biplano.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#15081(), name: "images/produzioni-tipiche/biplano.png", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: do you reach the catch clause in your code?

Answer (score 0):

you should just return a `string` for the image asset inside your `CircleAvatar` widget like the code below:

```
CircleAvatar(
            child: Image(
          image: AssetImage(getImage(snapshot.value['img'])),
        ))
```

the method returns a `string` now:

```
String getImage(String image) {
    String img;
    try {
      img = 'images/${widget.categoria}/$image.png';
    } catch (e) {
      img = 'images/non_disp_big.png';
    }
    return img;
  }
```

Comment: How can I check if this asset exist in my asset folder?

Comment: take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55025228/11385677).

Comment: I need something that return a string and not a Future, for now I had resolved removing data without an asset

Comment: in question you said to load default image when the asset image is not available which you can do that by `io.File(path).exists()` in an if statements as if it returns true then the file exists now you can set the image to that file and if it returns false now you can use the default image.

Comment: I have sobstituted the "path" with 'images/${widget.categoria}/$image.png' but return always false

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but the best way is user `errorBuilder` function that Image.asset provides and load for alternative widget.

```
 CircleAvatar(
      child: Image.asset(getImage(snapshot.value['img']),
      errorBuilder: ((context, error, stackTrace) => const Image.asset('images/non_disp_big.png')),
    )),
```